# Removing php5-fpm with apt asks to install apache

Tags: ubuntu, php

Hi I have been testing with (nginx and) hhvm as a faster alternative for php5-fpm. But removing php5-fm automatically install apache2 it seems. I dont need apache since i am using nginx. How do I prevent this ?

```
root@s2:~# apt-get remove php5-fpm
The following extra packages will be installed
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data libapache2-mod-php5 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap ssl-cert
the following packages will be removed
  php5-fpm
the following new packaged will be installed
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data libapache2-mod-php5 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap ssl-cert
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems like some packages depend on a running php. Run a reverse depends on php5-fpm, to find the possible candidates:

```
apt-cache rdepends php5-fpm
```

From the result you can decide to also remove the reverse depending packages as well, or to keep php5-fpm.

If you want to remove php5-fpm without taking care of any dependencies, you can run

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends php5-fpm
```

But next time oyu will use apt or dpkg you will have to fix the resulting errors (often described as dependency hell ;))